# Highlight cell based on a specific days - DATE - Need formula

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

- If the sold date is more than 180 days ago (compared to today) conditional format *red*
- If the Sold Date is 90 days ago or less (compared to Today) then make *green*
- If the sold date is less than 180 ago (compared to today) then make *yellow*

this needs to use a formula. TODAY must be a calculation so that as time changes, the colors of these fields changes

[image]

*Tried to use the formula on the right side however, all the cell range turned red

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) rules:

**Date is before > Exact date >**

`=today() - 180`

red

`=today() - 90`

yellow

`=today()`

green

Comment: Tried to use that but the cell range all turned red

Comment: The screenshot shows that you used **Custom formula is**. Use **Date is before > Exact date >** instead.